# MessageKit- SwiftUI Input Bar Placement on top of screen

Tags: swift, messagekit, inputbaraccessoryview

My application is in SwiftUI. I am implementing Message Kit as a chat feature, however, the input bar placement for the SwiftUI example in MessageKit awkwardly snaps to the top of the screen when the keyboard appears.

**Current SwiftUI Behavior:**
[image: Current SwiftUI Behavior]

**Expected Behavior(UIKit):**
[image: Expected Behavior(with UIKit)]

How can I fix the Inputbar placement for SwiftUI implementation or implement the expected Behavior within a SwiftUI app? Thanks

My code:

```
 func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MessagesViewController {
    let messagesVC = MessageSwiftUIVC()

    messagesVC.messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = context.coordinator
    messagesVC.messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = context.coordinator
    messagesVC.messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = context.coordinator
    messagesVC.scrollsToLastItemOnKeyboardBeginsEditing = true // default false
    messagesVC.maintainPositionOnInputBarHeightChanged = true // default false
    messagesVC.showMessageTimestampOnSwipeLeft = true // default false

    return messagesVC
  }
```

```
extension MessagesView.Coordinator: InputBarAccessoryViewDelegate {
    func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {
      let message = Message(sender: currentUser, messageId: "1", sentDate: Date(), kind: .text("Hello, World!"))

    messages.wrappedValue.append(message)
    inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution of this issue?